# Convert python-like list to R nested vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to "automatically" convert a data.frame column to multiple columns.

Here's what the df looks like :

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- data_frame(ID = c(1,2),
                  Val =  c("A", "B"),
                  Geom = c("[{X11,Y11,Z11}, {X12,Y12,Z12}, {X13,Y13,Z13}]", "[{X21,Y21,Z21},{X22,Y22,Z22},{X23,Y23,Z23}]"))
```

Here's what I would like it to look like :

```
bar <- data_frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                  Val=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                  Geom1 = c("X11", "X12", "X13", "X21", "X22", "X23"),
                  Geom2 = c("Y11", "Y12", "Y13", "Y21", "Y22", "Y23"),
                  Geom3 = c("Z11", "Z12", "Z13", "Z21", "Z22", "Z23"))
```

The workflow I consider for such a transformation consists of 2 parts :

1 - Convert Geom to a R structure, like :

```
list(c("X11","Y11","Z11"), c(...), ...)
```

2 - Use `tidyr::unnest()` or `tidyr::separate()` to split such list to columns

I think I can handle the second part, but can't find the good pointer for the first. I could write this column to a csv and read it automagically after, but considering my data.frame will be a shiny reactive object, that would involve a lot of writing/reading.

I tried to use `fromJSON()` (jsonlite, rjson and RJSONIO), but as this isn't valid json-string, it doesn't parse it.

Comment: @wildintellect on IRC told me that fromJSON works when replacing {} with []. I'll test those various solutions anyway and benchmark those, considering I prefer using pipes over temp variables :)

Comment: If you like pipes, you can rewrite the Colonel's answer like `setDT(foo)[, Geom %>% gsub(pattern='\\[{|}\\]', replacement='', perl=TRUE) %>% strsplit(split='}, *{', perl=T), .(ID, Val)]` or similar in dplyrish.

Comment: Did it without splitstackshape like this :
`setDT(foo)[,strsplit(gsub('\\[{|}\\]','', Geom, perl=T), '}, *{', perl=T), .(ID, Val)] %>%
  separate(V1, into = c("X", "Y", "Z"), convert = TRUE,  sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(UID = id(list(ID,Val)))`

Comment: Maybe separate could help with 1 too? `library(tidyr); foo %>% separate(Geom, letters[1:9], ',')`

Comment: For some implementations, at least, `fromJSON` will choke on `{X11, ` unless `X11` is quoted like `{'X11',`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `data.table`/`splitstackshape`:

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

dt = setDT(foo)[,strsplit(gsub('\\[{|}\\]','', Geom, perl=T), '}, *{', perl=T), .(ID, Val)]

cSplit(dt, 'V1')
#   ID Val V1_1 V1_2 V1_3
#1:  1   A  X11  Y11  Z11
#2:  1   A  X12  Y12  Z12
#3:  1   A  X13  Y13  Z13
#4:  2   B  X21  Y21  Z21
#5:  2   B  X22  Y22  Z22
#6:  2   B  X23  Y23  Z23
```

Comment: or use `tstrsplit`: `foo[, tstrsplit(strsplit(...)[[1]], ','), .(ID, Val)]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method using base R:

```
# vector to work with
geom <- c("[{X11,Y11,Z11}, {X12,Y12,Z12}, {X13,Y13,Z13}]", "[{X21,Y21,Z21},{X22,Y22,Z22},{X23,Y23,Z23}]")
# remove extraneous characters and split into list using "},"
geom <- strsplit(gsub("[]{ []", "", Geom), split="},")
# remove two "}"s
geom <- sapply(geom, function(i) gsub("}", "", i))
# make a list of elements
geom <- strsplit(geom, split=",")

# construct the variables
geomData <- data.frame(t(sapply(geom, function(i) sapply(1:3, function(row) c(i[row])))))
# give names to data frame
names(geomData) <- c("Geom1", "Geom2", "Geom3")

# final data.frame
fooNew <- cbind(foo[, 1:2], geomData)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) dplyr** This splits the data frame into rows and for each such row  uses `gsub` to split each triple onto a separate line and `read.table` to parse `Geom` further.  Then it fixes the column names and does an `ungroup`.  (The `setNames` line could be omitted if V1, V2 and V3 are OK instead of Geom1, Geom2 and Geom3.)

```
library(dplyr)

foo %>% 
   group_by(ID, Val) %>% 
   do(read.table(text=gsub("^..|..$|}, *{", "\n", .$Geom, perl=T), sep=",", as.is=T)) %>% 
   setNames(sub("^V(\\d+)", "Geom\\1", colnames(.))) %>%
   ungroup()
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]

     ID   Val Geom1 Geom2 Geom3
  (dbl) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
1     1     A   X11   Y11   Z11
2     1     A   X12   Y12   Z12
3     1     A   X13   Y13   Z13
4     2     B   X21   Y21   Z21
5     2     B   X22   Y22   Z22
6     2     B   X23   Y23   Z23
```

**2) No packages** This uses the same approach but without any packages.  The last line of code could be omitted if V1, V2, V3 are OK instead of Geom1, Geom2 and Geom3.

```
bar <- do.call("rbind", by(foo, foo$ID, function(x) 
   cbind(x[1:2], read.table(text = gsub("^..|..$|}, *{", "\n", x$Geom, perl=T), sep=","))))
names(bar) <- sub("^V(\\d+)", "Geom\\1", names(bar))
```

giving:

```
> bar
    ID Val Geom1 Geom2 Geom3
1.1  1   A   X11   Y11   Z11
1.2  1   A   X12   Y12   Z12
1.3  1   A   X13   Y13   Z13
2.1  2   B   X21   Y21   Z21
2.2  2   B   X22   Y22   Z22
2.3  2   B   X23   Y23   Z23
```